# Common function that calls a service to bind the directive attributes in component

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

I have a scenario where directive attributes are dynamic and are populated through service in the component. The component in turn is a child component and the `id` is passed as a `@Input` from the parent component. So, based on the `id` the service will fetch the corresponding attribute values for the directive.

There are number of child components and the service call piece of code (there are several attributes and not only 2) is repeated in all the components. Is there a way to achieve this in common place and used it across all the child components. Also, there are several parent components explained below and so moving this code to the parent component is not the one I am looking for.

**ParentComponent1 -> ChildComponent1, ChildComponent2**

**ParentComponent2 -> ChildComponent1, ChildComponent2**

**ParentComponent3 -> ChildComponent3, ChildComponent4**

Any other efficient way to achieve this?

**ChildComponent1.ts:**

```
export class ChildComponent1
{
      attr1: string;
      attr2: string;
      @Input() id: number;

      constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}

      ngOnInt()
      {
          this.someService.method1(id)
              .subscribe(data => { 
                    this.attr1 = data.attr1; 
                    this.attr2 = data.attr2; 
                         });
      }
}
```

**ChildComponent1.html:**

```
<directive1 [attr1]="attr1" [attr2]="attr2"></directive1>
```

The same for all other child components

Comment: What is wrong with your way? looks good